# sort in cakephp / fpdf

Tags: php, cakephp, fpdf

I have a small script created in CakePHP where I can generate quotes, however the quote items seem to be sorted in a non specific way on my PDF. What is the best way to have this sorted by ID in an ascending order ?

Find below my related code snippet which will list all items on my quote:

```
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemSubTotal = $item['quantity'] * $item['unit_price'];
        $discount_rate=$item['discount_rate'];
        $unit_price=$item['unit_price'];
        $subTotal += $itemSubTotal;
        $itemDiscount=$itemSubTotal*$discount_rate/100;
        $discount+=$itemDiscount;
        //$itemTax = $itemSubTotal * ($item['tax_rate'] / 100);
        $itemTax = ($itemSubTotal - $itemDiscount) * ($item['tax_rate'] / 100);
        $tax += $itemTax;
        $itemSubTotal = $itemSubTotal*((100-$discount_rate) / 100);
        $itemSubTotal = number_format($itemSubTotal, 2, '.', ',');
        $y+=5;
        $pdf->setXY(5, $y);
        $pdf->MultiCell(10, 5, $i++, 0, 'L');
        $pdf->setXY(15, $y);
        //$pdf->MultiCell(30, 5, $item['title'], 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(30, 5, $item['title'], 0, 2, 'L');
        $pdf->setXY(45, $y);
        //$pdf->MultiCell(80, 5, $item['details'], 0, 'L');
        $pdf->Cell(30, 5, $item['details'], 0, 2, 'L');
        $pdf->setXY(125, $y);
        $pdf->MultiCell(20, 5, $item['quantity'], 0, 'R');
        $pdf->setXY(145, $y);
        $pdf->MultiCell(15, 5, number_format($unit_price, 2, '.', ','), 0, 'R');
        $pdf->setXY(160, $y);
        $pdf->MultiCell(20, 5, number_format($discount_rate, 2, '.', ','), 0, 'R');
        $pdf->setXY(180, $y);
        $pdf->MultiCell(25, 5, $itemSubTotal, 0, 'R');
    }
```

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried this, but it should work. Have a look at [cake 3 collections](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/collections.html#Cake%5CCollection%5CCollection::sortBy) and specifically sortBy

If you wrap your $items in a collection, then sort them, then iterate through them you will achieve your goal.
Something like:

```
use Cake\Collection\Collection;

$collection = new Collection($items);
$sortedByField = $collection->sortBy('field')
```

If this doesn't work have a play with the other methods like groupBy

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful insight, appreciated

Comment: Glad I could help Dan